# Script Editor webpart works correctly only in editor mode

Tags: list, jsom, newform, userprofilemanager

I need customize NewForm for list for automatical filling some fields based on user's profile data. I add Script Editor webpart to NewForm.aspx page and write into this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UserProfiles.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var clientContext;
  var personProperties;

  $(document).ready(
    function(){
      SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
    }
  );

  function sharePointReady(){
    clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', getUserProperties);
  }


  function getUserProperties(){
    var targetUser = "<domain>\\<login>"; // I write real domain and login in this line

    var peopleManager = new SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager(clientContext);

    var profilePropertyNames = ["PreferredName", "Department", "Title"];
    var userProfilePropertiesForUser = new SP.UserProfiles.UserProfilePropertiesForUser(
        clientContext,
        targetUser,
        profilePropertyNames);
    var userProfileProps = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.load(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        function () { alert(userProfileProps[0] + " works in " + userProfileProps[1] + " as a " + userProfileProps[2]); },
        function () { alert("Failure") });
  }
</script>
```

In edit page mode code works fine.
In published page I get exception with text "TypeError: this.get_context is not a function" on this line:

```
var userProfileProps = peopleManager.getUserProfilePropertiesFor(userProfilePropertiesForUser);
```

Why it happens and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is because you are calling your function inside ready, call the below function outside ready function

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
```

Comment: In this case code is not working even in editor mode.

Comment: Check you may have other script errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

     clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.UserProfiles.js', 'SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager', getUserProperties);

});
```

Comment: This code is not working too.

Comment: Please add this script reference in your code: <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>

Comment: These libraries are not automatically loaded?

Comment: Yes they are. Sometimes it gives this kind of error

Comment: I added these libraries. Error is still there.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. None of the proposed solutions work.